# Vertical auto scroll, textarea pinned at bottom of div

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following list:

```css
.outer-container{ height: 300px; width: 300px;}

.container {
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.inner { 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;
}
.item{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
    
}
.add{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
    
}
.add textarea{
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="list">
                <div class="item">item</div>
                <div class="item">item</div>
                <div class="item">item</div>
                <div class="item">item</div>
                <div class="item">item</div>
                <div class="item">item</div>  
                <div class="item">item</div>
            </div>
            <div class="add">    
               <form>
                  <textarea placeholder="Add some text"></textarea>
               </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gubs5fg7/

The textarea will expand on input.

I'm trying to get the scroll to be active (overflow-y) on the div.list element only, i.e. textarea has no scrollbar beside it. I've a feeling I'll need to add a few more nested divs with absolute and relative positioning, but I wonder is there any way to get it working as it is now? (edit - is it possible without javascript?)

The height of the .outer-container div will be dependent on window size so won't always be 300px.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.outer-container{ height: 300px; width: 300px;}

.container {
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.inner { 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    overflow:vizibile;
}
.item{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.add{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
.add textarea{width: 100%; border: none;resize: vertical;}
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/gubs5fg7/2/

or for your need:

```
$('textarea').on('keypress',function(){
    $('.list').css({'margin-bottom': $('textarea').height()+'px'});
});
```

css:

```
.add {
    position: relative;
}
.add textarea{width: 100%; border: none;resize: vertical;
position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/gubs5fg7/5/

Comment: thanks for answering. This puts the scroll on the .container element, however, I would like the scroll to be on the .list element so that the text area is stuck to the bottom

Comment: thanks - this still doesn't work for me. I don't want there to be a scroll bar to the right of the text area at all - the text area should be the full width of the .outer-container. The scroll bar should span the .list div only, and only when required. I wonder is it possible to do it without javascript too